# cv2.VideoCapture() for IP webcam andriod

Tags: python, object-detection, opencv

**How can I feed IP webcam video in ImageAI video object detection?**
My code looks like this,

```
detector = VideoObjectDetection()
detector.setModelTypeAsYOLOv3()
detector.setModelPath(os.path.join(execution_path , "yolo.h5"))
detector.loadModel()
print('Model loaded')

capture = cv2.VideoCapture("http://10.10.1.223:8080/shot.jpg")

video_path = detector.detectObjectsFromVideo(camera_input=capture,
                            output_file_path=os.path.join(execution_path, "captured")
                            , frames_per_second=5, log_progress=True, detection_timeout=120)
```

When I use  cv2.VideoCapture(0) for my laptop's webcam, continuous frames are passed in my detector and a new video is created, however, whenever I pass the IP webcam link, it only processes one frame and then ends.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to answer my own question, I simply replaced shot.jpg from my URL to video. That's it!

I found out that if you access only the IP from your browser, you can copy the video address by browsing through Video rendered>>browser, simply right click and copy.